# How to interpret the cosine and sine of complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I know that the $\cos\left(a\right)$ return a point on the unit circle along the $x$ axis, who located at an angle $a$($a$ is **real** number). The $\sin\left(a\right)$ is analog for $\cos\left(a\right)$ but it return the point along $y$ axis.

Considering this, how to interpret the **cosine** and **sine** of complex number?

Given that the cosine and sine of a complex number will return total 4 values, I can suggest a point on the four-dimensional sphere, but it's just a fantasy.

**EDIT:** I am interested in geometric interpretation, according to the above analogy

Comment: I don't think that these have a geometric analogue.  It is worth noting, that the imaginary component behaves like a hyperbolic function.

Answer (score 1):

Use
$e^{ix}
=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)
$
and
$e^{-ix}
=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)
$
to get
$\cos(x)
=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2
$
and
$\sin(x)
=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)
$.

These hold for any complex x.

Note that if $x=u+iv$ 
where $u$ and $v$ are real
then
$e^x
=e^{u+iv}
=e^ue^{iv}
=e^u(\cos(v)+i\sin(v))
=e^u\cos(v)+ie^u\sin(v)
$
and
$e^{ix}
=e^{i(u+iv)}
=e^{iu-v}
=e^{-v}e^{iu}
=e^{-v}\cos(u)+ie^{-v}\sin(u)
$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$, we get $\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$ and $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$. Using the sum formulas, we get
$$
\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)
$$
and
$$
\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)
$$